# Disable select options based on value *through the HTML only!*

Tags: jquery, html, select

I need to disable a select option based on the value of a variable. The value is similar to one of the select option value and it needs to be disabled.

For ex,

```
<select>
<option>Value a</option>
<option>Value b</option>
</select>

$variable = <some select option value>;
```

So if variable is equal to Value a then it needs to be disabled in select option.

Thanks.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

With your current markup this will work:

```
$("select option:contains('Value b')").attr("disabled","disabled");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CtqC6/

EDIT

http://jsfiddle.net/CtqC6/1/

```
var variable = "b"
$("select option:contains('Value " + variable + "')").attr("disabled","disabled");
$("select").prop("selectedIndex",-1)
```

Comment: How do i add variable instead of Value b , also if the first option is set to be disabled it gets disabled only when the user clicks on the select menu.

Comment: You can make it dynamic by building the constructor with variables (see my edit).  Also, disabling the selected item works, it just doesn't deselect the selected item (also in my edit).

Answer (score 28):

```
$("select option[value='"+ $variable + "']").attr('disabled', true);
```

Answer (score 10):

This should be a faster solution

```
$('select').children('option[value="' + $variable + '"]').attr('disabled', true)
```

Answer (score 7):

**Let's say you had the following markup**

```
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

**Using this jQuery, the saab option would be disabled.**

```
$("select option").each(function() {
    var $thisOption = $(this);
    var valueToCompare = "saab";

    if($thisOption.val() == valueToCompare) {
        $thisOption.attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
});
```

[**Try it out here**](http://jsfiddle.net/d8ZjF/)