# Dynamically disable select menu based on text field value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'd like to be able to disable a select menu on my page when a user starts typing in a text field. This is because the text field is an alternative way to enter the data and disabling the dropdown menu will help make that clearer.

I know I could use this:

```
<select name="specialty" id="specialty" disabled="disabled">
```

to disable the select permanently, but is there a way to assign that attribute dynamically when the value of a text field changes? I know there is no css property to do it like there is for text inputs and textareas.

Something I found is a JQuery solution for disabling options within a select:

[Disable select options based on value *through the HTML only!*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7450370/disable-select-options-based-on-value)

I tried modifying this to disable the whole select but with no success (id of text field is testinput):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$("#testinput").change(function(){
    $("#specialty").attr("disabled","disabled");
}
);

</script>
```

This is a simplified version (the real function should check the length of the string in testinput and decide whether to disable or enable the select based on that), but if someone can help me get this working, then modifying it is easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, it works if the event handler is declared after the DOM is ready:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
$("#testinput").change(function(){
    $("#specialty").attr("disabled","disabled");
}
);
});

</script>
```

However, this way the selectbox will only disable after the input box has lost focus. You might want to use one of the key press events instead.

Comment: OK now there's something really confusing going on. I removed all the Javascript/JQuery from the page, including the event call, and now the select box is disabled all the time!

Comment: @robert: are you sure you've removed the `disabled="disabled"` from the HTML?

Comment: That was never in the HTML, and I just checked again, it's not there. This is really confusing. There is absolutely no Javascript being called on the page yet the select is disabled.

Comment: If there is no Javascript at all on the page, and the select box is not disabled with a HTML attribute, I can't think of a way it could possibly be disabled. Please verify it is not a caching issue (force refresh the page in your browser). If that doesn't solve it, please upload a test case.

Comment: I actually had to use JQuery to enable it - still not understanding this completely, but I got it to work. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

For the latest jquery versions, need to use prop() instead of attr().

```
$('#specialty').prop('disabled', true);
```

Also you can use focusin() and focusout() functions for this.

```js
//disable dropdown when entering text 
$('#testinput').focusin(function(){
    $('#specialty').attr('disabled',true);
});

//enable dropdown only if nothing entered
$('#testinput').focusout(function(){
  if($('#testinput').val().length == 0){
    $('#specialty').attr('disabled',false);
  }  
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Input: <input type="text" id="testinput"></td>
    <td>
      <select name="specialty" id="specialty">
        <option value="">--Select--</option>
      </select>
   </td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead of jQuery

```
document.getElementById('testinput').disabled = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 $("#specialty").attr("disabled", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work as written (see http://jsfiddle.net/3QXnq/ for example). But one thing to keep in mind - the onchange event for a text input only gets fired when the focus *leaves* the textbox. In other words, the dropdown won't be disabled until after they move on.

If you want to disable it as soon as they start typing, you'll want to use another event, such as onfocus or onkeydown.

Answer (score 0):

If using jQuery version > = 1.6, use prop() method for 'disabled'

http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Not exactly sure what test you want but here's the basics

```
$("#testinput").change(function(){                              
    var value=this.value;
    var test= value=='' || value.length===x;
    $("#specialty").prop("disabled",test);//  will enable/disable based on test

})
```