# Disable the Drop down options

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I want to disable the drop down options based on the condition. I want to disable all the other options except the option which has the text "Java".

Ex:

```
<select id="ddlList">
   <option value="csharp">C#</option>
   <option value="vb">VB.NET</option>
   <option value="jquery">jQuery</option>
   <option value="java">Java</option>
</select>
```

In this case Only java option should be enable and others should be disable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disable select options based on value \*through the HTML only!\*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7450370/disable-select-options-based-on-value-through-the-html-only)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*JQuery :*

```
$('#ddlList option:not([value=java])').prop('disabled', true);
```

#### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r2yp78y4/)

*JavaScript :*

```
 var filter = document.querySelectorAll('#ddlList option:not([value=java])')
 Object.keys(filter).forEach( function(g){ filter[g].disabled = true })
```

#### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r2yp78y4/3/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#ddlList option").each(function(){
    if(!$(this).val().contains("java"))
        $(this).attr('disabled', true);
});
```

This code lets you set the disabled attribute of each dropdown option by checking if its value contains "java"

[***JSFIDDLE DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/MR_Saberi/w8Lozj8n/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `disabled` property.

```
$("#ddlList option[value!='java']").prop("disabled", true);
```

If you want more control, in a more practical way, you can go over each option:

```
$("#ddlList option").each(function () {
    var allowed = ["java"];
    if (allowed.indexOf($(this).val()) === -1) {
        $(this).prop("disabled", true);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function optionDisable(selectId, optionIndex){
    document.getElementById(selectId).children[optionIndex].disabled="disabled";
}
```

or

```
document.getElementById(optionid).style.display = 'none';
```

or

```
function makeDisable(){
    var a=document.getElementById("ddllist")
    a.disabled=true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write your code like this:

```
Select Language: <select id="ddlList">
<option value="csharp">C#</option>
<option value="vb">VB.NET</option>
<option value="jquery">jQuery</option>
<option value="java">Java</option>
</select>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var condition = true;
    if(condition)
    {
        $("select option").prop('disabled',true);
        $("select option[value='java']").removeAttr('disabled');
        $("select").val("java")
    }
    else
    {
        //apply your logic here
    }
});
```

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/saikotju/7kf3tLc2/1/)