# jQuery to disable based on selected value

Tags: jquery, html, select, html-table

I have a page that pulls values from a database to create a table with 'td' elements defined as follows

```
  <td headers="STATUS">
    <label>Status</label>
    <select class="statusSelect">
        <option value="open">open</option>
        <option value="closed">closed</option>
        <option value="locked" selected="selected">locked</option>
    </select>
  </td>
```

I need to identify elements that have the value 'locked' and disable selection so that the user can't change the value in these cells.

There are other 'select' elements in the row that need to stay active so I have to make sure that only the 'select' element in this 'td' is affected.

Can I use jQuery to identify all of the elements that are 'locked' and disable the selection for these elements while leaving 'open' and 'closed' values enabled?

Comment: What do you mean by that last part, _"while leaving 'open' and 'closed' values enabled?"_ - do you want the user to be able to still select those in a select element that has one option with the value "locked"? Or do you not want them to change the selection in that whole select element at all? (Then how would the phrasing _"while leaving 'open' and 'closed' values enabled"_ make any sense?)

Comment: Just go through the below link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7450370/disable-select-options-based-on-value-through-the-html-only

Comment: Sorry. I meant that I don't want the user to be able to change the selection if  a value of 'locked' is brought back from the database. They should only be able to change the selection if a value  'open' or 'closed' is brought back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".statusSelect").change(function(){
       var optionVal=$(this).find(":selected").text();
           if(optionVal=='locked'){
            $(this).prop('disabled', true);
           }else{
            $(this).prop('disabled', false);
           }
    });
});
```

Please use this jquery to disabled or enable according to option.

Comment: Thanks! Worked great!

Comment: Welcome sir, i always here for help.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("option[value='locked']").attr('disabled', true);
```