# Select in Form of Angular6 work right first time

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6

When make a event the object parametersOfTest get new values and first time work right, but second time the button of form is disabled, the problem is in the select, but I don't understand because.

```
          <select  class="form-control" 
               [disabled]="modeEdit" 
               id="parameter" 
               required 
               name="parameter"  
               [(ngModel)] = "controlSelected.parameter"  
               #parameter>

        <option *ngFor="let parameterOfTest of parametersOfTest" 
                [ngValue]="parameterOfTest.id" >{{parameterOfTest.parameter}}</option>

      </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code, probably you are setting **`modeEdit`** to true once the first selection is made, if you really dont have any logic just remove that part,

```
  [disabled]="modeEdit"
```

Comment: Thanks, for answer! The problem was here [(ngModel)] = "controlSelected.parameter"

Answer (score 0):

You are disabling it with `modeEdit`, when you are submitting the form to component with `submit method`.So make sure that whats the actual purpose of that element.If you want to `disable`  the form with empty selection try this example

[Jquery select disable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7450370/disable-select-options-based-on-value-through-the-html-only/7450414))

and remove this disable attribute

```
[disabled]="modeEdit"
```

Comment: Thanks, for answer!  The problem was here [(ngModel)] = "controlSelected.parameter"